# Using config settings in attributes

Tags: c#, .net

I have a fragment of C# code that looks like this:

```
[OracleCustomTypeMapping(Constants.DBSchema + ".TAB_VARCHAR2_250")]
public class StringTableFactory : TableFactoryTemplate<StringTable>
{
    public override System.Array CreateStatusArray(int length)
    {
        return new OracleUdtStatus[length];
    }
}
```

Is there any way to change the attribute declaration, so Constants.DBSchema is read from web.config instead of having it hardcoded as a constant in code? If I put ConfigurationManager.appSettings in the attribute declaration, I am getting "An attribute argument must be a constant expression..." error.

Thanks.

Comment: Attribute arguments must be compile-time constants, which configuration settings obviously aren't. The best you could hope for using something that's wrapping configuration values is a `static readonly` field, which is run time constant (within the AppDomain), but isn't at compile time.

Comment: The error message explains it all. Attributes must be compile-time constants. Obviously, config settings are not.

Answer (score 12):

Rather than passing it in as part of the constructor arguments, read it direct from the `ConfigurationManager` in the Attribute's constructor.

```
public class OracleCustomTypeMappingAttribute : Attribute
{
    public OracleCustomTypeMappingAttribute(string typeName)
    {
        var schema = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Schema"];
        TypeMapping = schema + "." + typeName;
        // Or whatever property needs to be set
    }
}
```

Then you would just do:

```
[OracleCustomTypeMapping("TAB_VARCHAR2_250")]
public class StringTableFactory : TableFactoryTemplate<StringTable>
{
    public override System.Array CreateStatusArray(int length)
    {
        return new OracleUdtStatus[length];
    }
}
```

Comment: Little late on this, but what if the attribute is built-in and sealed?

Comment: Not really much you can do at that point. Attribute arguments have to be compile-time constants.